# Calender API for and employee training tracker

Tags: javascript, api

I am doing a group project and I am in charge of getting two APIs for an employee training tracker. I have the thought of a calendar API but I cannot find a basic one. Any ideas for a just a plain jane interactive calendar?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.